# Security Token Error in Docker Compose Up Command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, docker-swarm

I am trying to run docker container in ecs using docker compose.

I have build the image and created the context as well using

**docker compose create myecs**

But when i run the command `docker compose up` am getting the following error

```
UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
        status code: 400, request id: 0bb44cc9-4de3-4ac0-a6d5-685069dab0ee
```

aws configure output:

[image]

Comment: An invalid token message like that usually indicates that your local system clock does not have the correct time.

Comment: @mark8 what can be the solution to solve this problem